# Creating Wordpress Shortcode with Variable

Tags: php, functions, shortcode, variables

please forgive me I'm relatively new to PHP...

I would like to create a shortcode called [city-name] and have tried placing the following code in my functions.php file:

```
function get_city_name() {
return $current_cityinfo['cityname'];
}
add_shortcode( 'city-name', 'get_city_name' );
```

Then entered the [city-name] shortcode into a page to test and there is no luck...

Is there something wrong with my syntax.... I have entered the following into my category pages and that works absolutely fine:

```
<h1 class="loop-title"><?php single_cat_title(); ?> - <?php echo $current_cityinfo['cityname'];?></h1>
```

I hope someone can help me out here... been searching for over 2 hrs now and no luck so thanks in advance!

JAke

Comment: You have to define the variable `$current_cityinfo` inside `get_city_name()`, before you can use it - it is a PHP scope problem, read up on it. If it is a `global` variable, then do it by using the key word. Otherwise you have to use whatever logic is behind the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get $current_cityinfo first. As in:

```
$current_cityinfo = get_option('current_cityinfo');
```

Or add this code:

```
global $current_cityinfo;
```

above your `return` line.

Comment: There is no information, indeed, but it usually is. It's not a meta value and it's not a custom category value, so it must be an option.

Comment: I agree the original post lacks some information, but the user is "relatively new to PHP" so I suppose WordPress is not a strong feat.

Answer (score 1):

You should be passing the 'cityname' to your function:

```
function get_city_name($cityname) {
return $cityname;
}
add_shortcode( 'city-name', 'get_city_name' );
```

Your shortcode would then look like:

```
[city-name cityname="London"]
```

chances are that your function will return an array, but this should help you move forward

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so found the solution (sorry for the delay)

I had to put this:

```
// Add Shortcode
function city_name() {

 global $current_cityinfo; return ' '.$current_cityinfo['cityname'];

}

add_shortcode( 'city name', 'city_name' );
```

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. Can you mark the correct answer?